# Out of Memory error while creating table but SELECT works

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to CREATE a table using `CREATE TABLE AS`, which gives the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Out Of Memory: 
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Out Of Memory: 
  code:      1004
  context:   alloc(524288,MtPool)
  query:     6041453
  location:  alloc.cpp:405
  process:   query2_98_6041453 [pid=8414]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

I'm getting this error everytime I execute the query, but executing just the `SELECT` part of the query (without the `CREATE TABLE AS`) works fine. The result has around 38k rows. However I see there's a drastic difference in **Bytes returned** in the sequential scan on one table.

**SELECT**

[image]
[image]

---

**CREATE TABLE AS SELECT**
[image]
[image]

---

I fail to understand why there's so much difference between these two scenarios and what can be done to mitigate it. I also tried to create a `TEMP TABLE` but that also results in memory error.

I'm not great at understanding Query Plans (never found a detailed guide to it for Redshift, so if you could link to some resource that'd be a bonus).

**Update** : Also tried creating the table first and then INSERTing the data using SELECT, that also gives the same error.

**Update 2** : Tried `set wlm_query_slot_count to 40;` or even `50` but still the same error.

Comment: Have you opened a ticket for AWS support yet? We did and hopefully we'll have an answer quickly. There's been a maintenance update on Redshift a few days ago, that might be related.
In the meantime, you can make it work if you select less columns. I don't know in which extent you can do it but that's worth trying.

Comment: @anteverse It seems like I'm on basic support plan, so it'd be great if you could please update me here with your findings, it'll really help me understand this weird issue. Thanks

Comment: The Redshift team has released an update a few days later and after monitoring for a while, it seems a lot better for us. Any change on your side?

Comment: @anteverse I resorted to a workaround for this query, and that has been working fine. I'll try the original query and get back.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar issue after our clusters got updated to the latest release (1.0.10694).

Two things that helped:

- Changing your WLM to allocate more memory to your query (in our case,
  we switched to [WLM
  Auto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/workload-mgmt-config.html))
- Allocating a [higher query_slot_count to your query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_wlm_query_slot_count.html):
  `set wlm_query_slot_count to 2;` to allocate 2 query slots for
  example.

We suspect that AWS may have changed something with memory management with the most recent updates. I'll update once we hear back.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I am using auto WLM, and had actually tried setting `wlm_query_slot_count` to upto from 4-5 to upto 40-50, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could try inserting the records in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using manual WLM implement.